# Word / phrase for a simulation that is in-sync with the real-world

Tags: technology, computers

If it starts raining in the real world, it will rain in the simulation as well. I've got as far as simultaneous-simulation / synchronous-simulation but is there something better?

Comment: This is an idea generation question and is generally frowned upon in Stack Exchange questions.  But is it a mirroring effect, so something like a Mirror-Sim?

Comment: @bowlturner +1 for the Mirror effect, simple yet elegant.

Comment: As bowlturner says, idea generation questions aren't generally a great fit for SE as they usually just generate long lists.

Comment: This sounds like a question for English use SE

Comment: @MarchHo  I don't know that it would be better on English than here.  It's not like there is currently enough real world mirror simulations that there would be a word for it.  We may be a better place for a purely speculative, science-based answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basicly, it's a **simulated** (synchronous) **parallel universe**

Comment: To me that does not carry the ring of being in sync with reality. Like "parallel universe" both in cosmology and fiction that could be just alternative universes or worlds, which are not synced with one another.

Comment: Agree, addet synchronous.

Comment: All the replies have been helpful. Just to muddy the waters I'm now wondering if 'simulation' helps at all - perhaps what I'm conceiving is simply a 'virtual dimension' of the real world. :P  Thanks all.

Comment: I do not recommend the term dimension. You should get an idea of how dimension is defined. We got 3 spacedimensions and that, as far is we know, single timedimension. There are clues but no prove that there might exist other dimensions but that has nothing to do with what you want to describe.

Answer (score 0):

I think `Life` would be good word to use. so for me it would be `Synchronous life simualtion`.

Answer (score 0):

I'll take a stab at this one before it gets placed on hold :) Universe Synch-ulation? Just a simple mashup of the two words